# Update Timestamp after jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter reads a record from DB

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring integration's "int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter" to fetch records from the DB. However after I fetch records I also need to update 2 columns 
       1) Status column 
       2) Timestamp columns

Updating the status column is not an issue as I can use below xml snippet

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
    channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
    update="update item set status=10 where id in (:id)" />
```

However when I try to update timestamp, it doesnt work

```
    <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
        channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
        update="update item set status=10,timestamp=:timestamp where id in (:id)" 
         update-sql-parameter-source-actory="timestampUpdaterSqlParameterSourceFactory">
     <int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>


    <bean id="timestampUpdaterSqlParameterSourceFactory"
          class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory"  >
        <property name="parameterExpressions">
            <map>
                <entry key="timestamp" value="@now"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

<bean id="now" scope="prototype" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
    <constructor-arg value="#{ T(java.lang.System).currentTimeMillis()}" />
</bean>
```

We can use DB level methods to set the time like sysdate for oracle, but I am not keen on using DB specific methods in code for testing purposes(H2 DB used for testing)

Any Help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You know, have just tested your code with HSQL - works well. Maybe `timestamp` is a key word for H2? How does the problem look for you?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the problem is that `:timestamp` expression is evaluated as a [Collection Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-projection), check the [code here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory.java#L120).
So my Original query was something like this

```sql
update table set status = 1, published_at = :now where id_event in (:id)
```

After the parsing was something like this

```
update table set status = 1, published_at = ?, ?, ? where id_event in (?, ?, ?)
```

The numbers of `?` is the same as the number of results from the `select` statement. So if the result is more than one, you get a Bad Grammar exception.

I made a not very nice solution (intrusive) using `spring-integration-java-dsl`

```java
  protected void addNotCollectionProjectionExpression(
      ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory factory,
      String key, String expression) {
    try {
      Field parameterExpressionsField = factory.getClass().getDeclaredField("parameterExpressions");
      parameterExpressionsField.setAccessible(true);
      Map<String, Expression[]> parameterExpressions = (Map<String, Expression[]>) parameterExpressionsField
          .get(factory);

      Field parserField = factory.getClass().getDeclaredField("PARSER");
      parserField.setAccessible(true);

      ExpressionParser parser = (ExpressionParser) parserField.get(factory);

      Expression compiledExpression = parser.parseExpression(expression);
      Expression[] expressions = new Expression[]{
          compiledExpression,
          compiledExpression
      };
      parameterExpressions.put(key, expressions);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      logger.error("Field parameterExpressions | PARSER can not be obtained", e);
    }
  }
 ....
//how to use it
ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory factory =
        new ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory();
    addNotCollectionProjectionExpression(factory, "now",
        "T(com.example.MyClass).staticMethod()");
    return factory;
```

You can notice that I am avoiding to use Collection Projection using the same expression in both elements of the array.