# Update query with time of select query through a int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: sql, spring-integration, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

What I am trying to perform is to consume messages with a *int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter* linked to some datasource, and then update a *consumer_table* (or offsets table) that would retain, for a specific key, the exact date of query

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter
...
    query="someSelect" 
    update="someUpdate" 
    update-sql-parameter-source-factory="someCustomSqlParameterSourceFactory">
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

| group_id | latest_consultation |
| --- | --- |
| someGroupId | 2023-11-01 19h30 |
| someOtherGroupId | 2023-12-04 19h30 |

| id | priority | payload | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | [BLOB] | 2023-12-01 18:20:00.000 |
| 2 | 1 | [BLOB] | 2023-12-05 18:30:00.000 |
| 3 | 1 | [BLOB] | 2023-12-10 18:27:00.000 |

Basically, I will have 2 queries:

```
SELECT NOW() as now_,id,payload,priority 
  FROM myDb.messages m
  WHERE m.creation_date > 
     (select o.latest_consultation from myDb.offsets o where o.group_id = 'someGroupId')
```

AND

```
REPLACE INTO myDb.offsets (group_id,latest_consultation) values ('someGroupId', :now_)
```

The problem here is that the *:now_* expression will be evaluated as collection
It is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45760587/498190) , with a start of a solution.
But with the trick of the above link, it will point to a static method, that will not have access to the input data , and thus the *now_* value (or not in a way I understand).
Admittedly, this way I can provide a timestamp computed on the run, but it may be slightly different from the *now_* value. It may be very short, but with billions of messages per hour, this may occasionnaly result in some message being missed in the meantime.  Thus, I need it to be ***now_***

Thus, I am trying to find a way to pass the exact time of the *select* query to the *update* query as a single element (and not a collection)

Any (new) idea?

**Edit 1**
I tried Artem Bilan's solution : using *update-per-row="true"*
I had to replace *replace into* with *update where...* because *now_* was not recognized as a Timestamp, but as an object. Basically, I had :

> PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [replace into moba.offsets (group_id,latest_consultation) values
> ('valdimir', ?) ]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Type
> java.lang.Object not supported type

With an *update* clause, combined with *update-per-row="true"*, it does the trick. However, I compared performances with and without *update-per-row*, and for 3000 records, I went from 5 mins to 1,5 mins.... This is a hudge downgrade in message rate. I'd rather find a less invasive method if possible.

(though, my use case was actually not realistic : I consumed them as once, while the polling pattern will act closer to the  *update-per-row="true"* use case)

Comment: See if `update-per-row="true"` helps you somehow. There is also `max-rows="1"` to limit the number of records returned by the `SELECT`

Comment: @ArtemBilan yes, that does the trick... but I had to replace "replace" query with "update" .. and also it is a huge downgrade on performances... which I can't afford. I am updating my post with more accurate info

Comment: Another way is to use stored procedure instead. So, you would be able to perform `SELECT` and `REPLACE` on DB and only after that return whatever data you need in the application: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/jdbc/stored-procedures.html#stored-procedure-inbound-channel-adapter

Comment: @ArtemBilan This way, it looks to me that I am loosing the transactionnal factor (From inbound adapter to  outbound adapter)

Comment: Not sure why. The procedure still can be called withing transaction started from your application.

Comment: It is also not clear from your explanation why would you return so many rows from that SELECT since you talk only about `NOW()`. The single `UPDATE` also can be used. And for that purpose you need to look into an `in(:now_)` clause. See in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/jdbc/inbound-channel-adapter.html

Comment: About the procedures, I think I understand the way to do it without breaking the transactionnal factor. My bad, I answered too fast. About the in(:now_) clause, I don't understand. Also I admit I may not have that many rows that often (usually, 1 to 50 rows max). So update-per-rows may eventually match my goal. I will try to do some bench here

Comment: When SELECT returns a list and you'd like to have a single UPDATE for it, then you have to use `in()` clause over there to be able to inject values from that returned list.

Comment: So, are we good so far? Can I shape this discussion into an answer to help others with similar concerns?

Comment: Yes, sounds ok to me with your many hints... though I must confess that even with the doc I was not able to understand your in() explanation. Thus if you can develop a little bit, I guess that would help (and not only me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `SELECT` returns several rows and you intend to use a single `UPDATE` for all of them, then you need to consider to use `in(:now_)` clause in the `UPDATE`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/jdbc/inbound-channel-adapter.html

> The parameters in the update query are specified with a colon (:) prefix to the name of a parameter (which, in the preceding example, is an expression to be applied to each of the rows in the polled result set). This is a standard feature of the named parameter JDBC support in Spring JDBC, combined with a convention (projection onto the polled result list) adopted in Spring Integration.

The logic there is like this:

```
"#root.![" + paramName + "]"
```

which is a `collection projection`: build a new collection selecting a particular property of the original collection elements: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/collection-projection.html

If you still cannot use that, there is an option like `update-per-row="true"`. See the same docs about JDBC Inbound Channel Adapter.

You also may consider to use `max-rows="1"` if the logic falls into a conclusion that only one item must be returned from `SELECT`.

Another solution is to use stored procedure to perform everything on the DB side: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/jdbc/stored-procedures.html